# Embedding large equation in tabular

Tags: math-mode, equations, tables

When I put an equation in a tabular, it gets vertically compressed.  How do I prevent that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Put `\displaystyle` inside your `\(  \)` or `$ $`.

Added: The issue here actually has nothing to do with tables (unless I'm missing something). It's just about inline as opposed to displayed math.

Comment: Correct addition. I take the opportunity to add the mathmode tag.

Comment: Actually, I think it does have something to do with tables. It does not seem possible to put `$$x^2$$` for instance in a table cell.